# How many 5 card hands can be made if there must be 3 of one face value and 2 other cards with different face values?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How many 5 card hands can be made if there must be 3 of one face value and 2 other cards with different face values?

Can you help me to find out the answer with explanation? I did not understand the question exactly.

The answer is: ${3 \choose 1}\cdot{4 \choose 3}\cdot{4 \choose 1}\cdot{4 \choose 1}$ but I did not understand the question.

Comment: Well, I don't think the question is clear.  Would $KKKQQ$ be a good hand? Or do you need something like $KKKQJ$?

Comment: You have $3$ choices for the first card, ...

Comment: Assuming you are looking for a three of a kind (and specifically not a full house) Choose the number for the triple.  Choose the three suits used for the triple.  Chose the two numbers which are not used for triple simultaneously.  Choose suit for the smaller singleton.  Choose suit for larger singleton.  Apply multiplication principle and win.

Comment: Also, does "face value" just mean "value"?  Initially, I took it to mean "face card"  as in $J,Q,K$ but now I think you just meant "value", so a hand like $77789$ would be good.

Comment: The answer is: (3 choose 1)*(4 choose 3)*(4 choose 1)*(4 choose 1) but I did not understand the question so, can you explain more, please?

Comment: Well, that answer is consistent with "face card" and with the "no full house" rule. There are three possible face cards ($J,Q,K$ as I said).  choose one to make the triple, that's the $\binom 31$.  Then pick three of that value, that's the $\binom 43$.  Then pick one card of one of each of the other face cards, those are the last two $\binom 41$ terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have to pick the face card that we will use for the first $3$ cards. We can do this in $3$ ($\binom{3}{1}$) ways, since there are $3$ face cards ($K, Q, J$). Then we need only $3$ of the $4$ copies of that rank ($K$, $Q$, or $J$) so we multiply by $\binom{4}{3}$.

Having used one rank ($K$, $Q$, or $J$) there are two ranks left, and we need one card from each rank. (The question is not clear on this, the way you wrote it, but based on the answer this is what was intended!)
So we pick one card from the first rank in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, and one card from the second rank in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.

In total we have now picked five cards, and we have not overcounted; we have uniquely determined a set of five cards. So the total number of ways is
$$
\binom{3}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{4}{1} \binom{4}{1}.
$$